# Error al generar usuarios en SQL file

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Recibo el siguiente error:

> ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 11: Operation DROP USER failed for 'garen'@'localhost'

Cuando ejecuto este código:

```
-- DATABASE 
-- Creamos la base de datos
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS janitza511;
CREATE DATABASE janitza511;
USE janitza511;

-- USER 
-- DROP USER IF EXISTS "garen"@"localhost";
-- Creamos el usuario para la base de datos
-- Se dropea del todo a causa de mysql no acepta "IF EXISTS"
DROP USER garen@localhost;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
CREATE USER garen@localhost  IDENTIFIED BY 'CONTRASEÑA';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO "garen"@"localhost" WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

El comando si lo pongo yo a mano, funciona a la perfeccion; pero si lo hago desde un sql, no.

Estoy trabajando con MySQL y en una RaspberryPi 3.

Comment: Ya esta copiado el texto de la imagen.

Comment: ¿Lo ejecutas en ambos casos con el mismo usuario?

Comment: No, es parte de un sql de una instalación... Es decir, he creado un archivo .deb de instalación y ese archivo debe crearse.

Comment: Entonces cuando ejecutas el script tú mismo lo haces con un usuario determinado, pero y el script .deb, ¿quién lo ejecuta? Seguramente es un tema de permisos.

Comment: A ver, es parte de un .deb yo solo hago un "dpkg -i" para instalar del .deb y eso deberia ejecutarse con la instalacion

Comment: Pero entonces, ¿cuál es el comando que ejecutas tras el cual te sale el "ERROR 1396..."? ¿`dpkg -i`?

Comment: A ver, ese error ocurre cuando yo importo manualmente el .sql al mysql, porque no funciona automaticamente. Estoy probando yo manualmente, y cuando funcione, supongo que lo hara automaticamente.

Comment: ¿Pero qué comando ejecutas? ¿Lanzas el código desde la consola de MySQL? Nótese que insisto tanto en esto porque mencionas que "si lo pongo yo a mano, funciona a la perfección", por lo que es importante saber en qué condiciones _no_ funciona.

Comment: _An error occurs if you try to drop an account that does not exist._ dice la documentación. Luego, es un bug de MySQL no poder usar `IF EXISTS ...` y en realidad no se entiende por qué no lo corrigen. Puedes hacer lo siguiente para evitar que te de ese error en caso de que el usuario no exista: `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
   DROP USER 'username'@'localhost';` Ver [MySQL bugs](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19166), es la solución aportada por Steve Bearman el [30 Mar 2007 7:11] Ah y yo no usaría `Ñ` ni acentos ni caracteres especiales en los nombres de columna-tablas.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano solucionado. Y lo de usar la Ñ no la voy a usar, es por no poner la contraseña real.

Comment: Sería bueno una respuesta indicando la solución, para que la pregunta no quede abierta.

Comment: Ya esta. Respuesta con la solucion.

Answer (score 0):

La solucion es usar:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
DROP USER 'username'@'localhost';
```

`GRANT USAGE` evita que dé el error "Operation DROP USER failed..." en caso de que el usuario no exista.